# STM32l1xx I2C with HAL library

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal, slave

I am working on a project where I need to set a STM32L152RDT6 as a slave with I2C but I can't get it.
I tried this but it failed:

```
 HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(&hi2c1);
 I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

 uint8_t aRxBuffer[1];
 uint8_t aTxBuffer[] = " ****I2C_TwoBoards communication based on Polling****  ****I2C_TwoBoards communication based on Polling****  ****I2C_TwoBoards communication based on Polling**** ";

    if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 1, 10000) != HAL_OK)
        {
          /* Transfer error in reception process */
          Error_Handler();
        }
      else{
          printf("succeed\n");
           printf("I2C data: %d ",aRxBuffer[0]);
      }

    void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2cHandle)
    {
       /* Turn LED6 on: Transfer in reception process is correct */
        printf("Amazing\n");
    }
```

I need an example which set a STM32 as a slave with I2C using HAL library please.

Thank you so much !!

Comment: What is the failure? Any error messages?

Comment: @Rastalamm HAL doesn't return any useful error codes or messages.

Comment: I'm quite certain there is an I2C master-slave example shipped with HAL.

Comment: @Rastalamm It compile successfully but when I use arduino as a master and sent a byte to STM32 it didn't work.

Comment: With     ```HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 1, 10000)``` you want to receive one byte within 10000 Ticks. Are you sure that the master sends the byte in this time? Try     ```HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY)```  instead.